# How to calculate length of records of model if records of model are changed based on filtration condition?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/12/).

On click of type1 and type2 link i am filtrating data on some condition and because of this filtration i am not able to calculate total no of records in every scenario.

I should be able to calculate total no of records and total no of records of type1,type2 in  each filtration.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
         total:function(){ 
           return this.get('content.length'); 
         }.property('content.length'),
         total1: function() {
           return this.get('content').filterProperty('contacttype', 1).get('length');
         }.property('content.@each.contacttype'),
         total2:function(){ 
           return this.get('content').filterProperty('contacttype', 2).get('length');
         }.property('content.@each.contacttype')
    });
```

Comment: @intuitivepixel  Yes,it is working fine for single condition i.e. if it is case of all records without any filtration.But for multiple filtration i have posted this new question.

Comment: @intuitivepixel : sorry,i will give you proper feedback now onward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the thing, with the new router that has been introduced in ember, every time you override the 'setupController' method, you need to send to 'super' the controller and the model again, there's an explanation why ember developers did this, you can find it on the internet, so, you have to do this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    var cont = App.Person.find();
    controller.set('filtereddata', cont);
  },
  model: function() {      
    return App.Person.find();
  }
});
```

you also need to do the same with the other routes